# Rails Nested SQL Queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a database model `Position(lat,lon)` which holds `latitudes` and `longitudes.`

I have a controller action called `show_close_by` which recieves a position in degrees `(my_lat, my_lon)`, a tolerance (in kilometers) and should return the list of positions in the database that are within tolerance range.

For that, I use the haversine_distance formula which calculates the distance in kilometers (on the surface of the Earth) between two coordinates `(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)`.

To make the query faster, I wrote the whole `haversine_distance` formula in the query:

```
... WHERE 2*6371*asin(sqrt( power( sin( (:lat2-latitude)*pi()/(180*2) ) ,2) + cos(latitude*pi()/180)*cos(:lat2*pi()/180)*power(sin( (:lon2-longitude)*pi()/(180*2) ),2) )) < tolerance
```

The specifics of the query don't matter. My doubt is: is it necessary to calculate this huge function for EVERY position in the database? Can I filter out some positions that are clearly too far away with a simpler function?

Well, I can: With a nested SQL query, I can query the database for positions that are within a large "square" (in lat/lon space), and then filter those with the more costly trigonometric function. Something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM Positions WHERE lat-latitude < some_reasonable_upper_bound AND lon-longitude < same_upper_bound ) WHERE costly_haversine_distance < tolerance
```

Finally, my question: how can I implement this in Rails (without writing the whole query myself)? Does `Positions.where(reasonable_upper_bound).where(costly_but_accurate_restriction)` make a nested query? If not, how?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know about [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)? You install the gem, add a line in your Position model, and then you can do stuff like `Position.near([40.71, 100.23], 20)`. This gem is quite popular, so I'd say they do what you wanna do pretty well. (juts so you know, linking `where` clauses does not do what you want. I think it just overrides the previous ones).

Comment: Yeah, I know about Geocoder and I might just end up using it, but it seemed a bit big for what I want (I just want distances between objects). How much slower is an app that loads a whole Geocoder object compared to the barebones haversine_distance function I programmed?

Comment: @Robin It doesn't override the previous one, but it *does* append the conditions using `AND` to the current query, which isn't quite what the asker is looking for.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's how to make nested queries:

```
LineItem.where(product_id: Product.where(price: 50))
```

It makes the following request:

```
SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" 
WHERE "line_items"."product_id" IN 
(SELECT "products"."id" FROM "products" WHERE "products"."price" = 50)
```

Note that **only** `id`s will be fetched from the `products` table. If you are trying to make another way to connect two entities and this magic isn't suitable, use `Product.select(:some_field).where(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the post but I need little different help.. How to write query if I need to select all messages communicated between two user(say id1 & id2) and message have sender_id and receiver_id. So i need to select "all messages whose ((sender_id = id1 and reciver_id = id2) or (sender_id = id2 and reciver_id = id1))" in rails. I need to sort them out and paginate which can not be done if I make two separate query and then add them(I will have the desired result but pagination becomes difficult). So please help me out in writing single line query for this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @zeal Try https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel for complicated queries.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest an updated answer. In Rails v5.0.x, you can use `select` to use an attribute other than id while still doing a nested query.

```
LineItem.where(product_id: Order.where(price: 50).select(:product_id))
```