# Convert Ruby mapping statement to ActiveRecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

In my DB I've got a many-to-many relationship ([HABTM](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)) between Users and Roles. I'm trying to get all role names for users associated with a particular secretary.

I managed to cobble the following together:

```
class Secretary < ActiveRecord::Base
  def getRoles
    rolenames = Set.new
    Role.all.map { |role| role.users.map { |user| rolenames << role.name if user.manager.secretary == self } }
    rolenames.to_a
  end
end
```

...which works, but it seems like a properly crafted "where" statement ought to produce the same result without hitting the database so much.

Is it possible to convert the above to a more "native" ActiveRecord query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given enough information to get a clear picture of your model. From what you did provide I'm guessing it looks like this from the point of view of the secretary:

```
Secretary
 has_many :managers

Manager
 has_namy :users

User
 has_many :roles
```

When retrieving records from deeply nested models it's helpful to think in terms of the id's(foreign keys): [Rails Nested SQL Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147289/rails-nested-sql-queries)

Since Rails automatically converts records into id's for you inside the hash version of a where statement..

```
Role.where(:user_id => User.where(:manager_id => managers))
```

should get your answer if my assumptions about your model are correct.

EDIT:
Okay, HABTM muddies the water a bit. We can't do nested where's but we can still do a where along with some mapping without hitting the database too hard. Try this:

```
User.includes(:roles).where(manager_id: managers).flat_map(&:roles).map(&:name)
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the relationship between Users and Roles is a HABTM relationship (has_and_belongs_to_many, with a join table). Managers do have many users of the system, and secretaries do have many managers. So the query should return the set of roles on all users under a given manager under a given secretary. Does that clarify the question?

Comment: The inner query works, but the outer `Role.where(:user_id => ...)` query doesn't seem to return anything. I also tried `Role.include(:users).where(:user_id => ...)` with similar results.

Comment: I assume you are in the console. Add .to_sql and see what you get. There should be 2 IN clauses with id's in the parens.

Comment: Correction: the inner where should generate an IN clause with id's, the outer where should generate an IN clause with a select statement. Maybe there is no data to retrieve? Seems to work here - Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.8

Comment: Looking at the output of .to_sql, I'm thinking the issue must be related to the first of the two "IN"s. In other words, `WHERE "roles"."user_id" IN` doesn't work because of the HABTM relationship. There is a join table, so there is no `"user_id"` column directly on the Roles table. I suppose the question is, how to get at the `"user_id"` via the join table?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36493/discussion-between-seph-and-user456584)

Comment: @user456584 please see edit above. This should work with HABTM.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your models are like this:

```
Role 
  has_many :users
User 
  belongs_to :role 
  has_one :manager, :class => 'User'
```

In the case, just inner joining the tables shall bring back the results you are after:

```
SELECT roles.* FROM roles
INNER JOIN users u ON u.role_id = roles.id
INNER JOIN users m ON m.id = u.id
```

This query can be translated to something like this:

```
Role.joins(:users => :manager)
```