# Select top N percent from query in ActiveRecord, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

How can I select the top N percent of the rows of a table, according to some order clause? Hopefully with only one query to the database

According to [this discussion](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4CBB8C87.8020409@darrenduncan.net), the following is a way to select the top 10% rows from a table from PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM mytbl ORDER BY num_sales DESC LIMIT
    (SELECT (count(*) / 10) AS selnum FROM mytbl)
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10148007/893510), nesting a query inside a where clause in ActiveRecord will generated a nested SELECT, instead of firing two queries:

```
Item.where(product_id: Product.where(price: 50))
```

How can something like this be done in ActiveRecord without too much SQL?

Comment: Any problem with `find_by_sql`?

Comment: I was hoping for an ActiveRecord solution, as the SQL can get pretty ugly and I want to use it in scopes

Comment: Perhaps passing SQL to the limit() method wouldn't be that bad, but that is not permitted apparently

Answer (score 3):

It would not be very inefficient to do this:

```
total_rows = MyClass.count
limit_rows = (0.1 * total_rows).to_i
MyClass.order("num_sales desc").limit(limit_rows)
```

Or of course:

```
MyClass.order("num_sales desc").limit((0.1 * MyClass.count).to_i)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I meant with one query. It's a critical request and a huge table so it's important to do all in one query. I added this to the question.

Comment: There's not much inefficiency in this method, other than executing two queries instead of one. The overhead of that is very small because you're just selecting a single value and then passing it straight back. In the context of a "select an ordered 10% of a huge table" query it's going to be negligible.